# Angular Upgrade - can't use upgraded component as entry component

Tags: angular, angular-hybrid

I'm using Angular Upgrade module with components upgraded from AngularJS. When I use components inside templates they are working fine but when I try to use them as entry components I receive an error:

```
MyNgComponent cannot be used as an entry component.
```

Probably it's because upgraded components are defines as directives. I've also tried to wrap into another component but in this case it gives me an error when tries to create a component instance:

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for $scope!
```

`$scope` is requested by internal UpgradeComponent implementation and it's resolved fine if component is used in a template.

Is it a hybrid mode limitation or is there any way to use it as entry component?

Entry component is needed because I need to instantiate this component from JS and manually attach to non-angular DOM element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a limitation of a hybrid mode. In my case it was necessary to dynamically create upgraded components and attach them to DOM. In this case it's possible to use the following workaround:

1. Create a regular Angular Component as a wrapper for upgraded AngularJS directive so that it's template only contains an upgraded directive
2. Add this wrapper component to `entryComponents` module section
3. Dynamically instantiate this wrapper component using an injector of root hybrid component

For example, I have a have a dummy AngularJS directive

```
angular.module('app').component('myComponent', {
  template: 'dummy content',
  controller: class {},
  controllerAs: 'vm'
});

@Directive({
  selector: 'my-component'
})
export class MyUpgradedDirective extends UpgradeComponent {
  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {
    super('myComponent', elementRef, injector);
  }
}
```

Create a wrapper component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nested',
  template: '<my-component></my-component>'
})
export class WrapperComponent { }
```

Add it to `entryComponents`

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, UpgradeModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, NestedComponent, MyUpgradedDirective ],
  entryComponents: [ AppComponent, NestedComponent ] // here
})
```

Create a wrapper instance using an injector from root hybrid component:

```
function createMyComponent<T>(componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, injector: Injector /* must be passed from root hybrid component */, component: Type<T>) {
  return componentFactoryResolver
    .resolveComponentFactory(component)
    .create(injector);
}
```

Here are some details: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27432